# How to prevent users from ordering outside restaurants in a Laravel + Vue.js Delivery System?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, web

I'm working on an app with Laravel + VUE.JS that allows the user to go to the restaurant put his cellphone on a QRCODE on a table and make an order.

When he is making the order he sends this data to my application that will put him in the row of orders and will show on a TV in the restaurant.

All tables will have a QRCODE with the link to the application that will have products.

How can I prevent this user from his home access this link and make the order?

Token validation with an expiration time in QR CODE? Location?

Comment: Set the server up in the restaurant, disconnected from the web, in a LAN configuration.

Comment: Like a local server? so every time my client needs to connect to the lan?

Comment: With a WiFi. I have a homenetwork. If I connect a linux desktop to the network, then I'll have a server running on it as well. Bridge your WiFi modem to the desktop and done, Expiring QR codes ok, but how will you update the QR code after every use?

Comment: you can get location of client phone and match with hotel location distance

Comment: Make the user connect with a WIFI is not that good, in my country people don't like to do that. The location solution is good but I have afraid of people that want to make a joke from the system.

Comment: If your QR codes are fixed then you could potentially have a code that updates every few minutes that the users have to put into the app as well. This wouldn't be foolproof but it would give a bit more protection. Failing that, you could have it so one of the staff has to "approve" a phone connecting to the app or at least "opens" the table.